working in postman ,but not working from vb.net code,giving internal error
when trying to send the request through postman ,works fine . but gives the following error ,when using it direct from vb.net code
we are using Lib  RestSharp  and version 106.15.0.0
the error messaage as flollows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Internal Error (from client)</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>

Headers
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("X-Client-Id", "78a7babff8feb0aed964113c867288b7")
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxxx")
    request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
    request.AddHeader("Content-Length", 1420?)

Json Body
    {
    "billNumber": "R2LEH003776X",
    "internalInvoiceNumber": "6666",
    "paymentMethod": "s",
    "invoiceIssueDate": "2024-05-11",
    "invoiceDueDate": "2024-05-12",
    "invoiceDescription": "",
    "billerVATNumber": 333,
    "companyName": "",
    "companyRegistrationNumber": 1234567890,
    "consumerEmail": "xx@xx.dd",
    "consumerMobile": "",
    "customerVATNumber": "",
    "buildingNumber": 4562,
    "additionalNumber": 7122,
    "street": "INDUSTRIAL STREET",
    "district": "",
    "postalCode": 12333,
    "city": "",
    "province": "",
    "country": "",
    "totalBeforeVAT": 1000.92,
    "totalVAT": 150.14,
    "grandTotal": 1151.06,
     "item":[
        {
          "invoiceLineSerialNo": 1,
          "itemCode": 100,
          "itemDescriptionArabic": "container BGHJ8777",
          "itemDescriptionEnglish": "",
          "unitOfMeasureArabic": "Unit",
          "unitOfMeasureEnglish": "",
          "itemPrice": 500.4586,
          "quantity": 2,
          "lineItemAmount": 1000.92,
          "lineItemDiscount": 0,``your text``
          "lineItemDiscountAmount": 0.0,
          "lineItemAmountAfterDiscount": 1000.92,
          "lineItemVAT": 15,
          "lineItemTotalVAT": 150.14,
          "lineItemTotal": 1151.06
        }
    ]
    }


my experience is that this sort of error is often a data type problem. Check whether you have a field defined as Integer when it should be a Decimal etc.
The Line Item Discount "your text" bit looks weird too

If you use the latest version of RestSharp, you should not set content type, accept, and content length headers.

Problem solved ,i found the problem was using old version of Restsharp.dll ,i replaced with the latest one 111.2.0
